# Database choices with modelchoiceform connection

Tags: python, django, database, forms

Now I have a model field with choices like that
models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = 'US'
    training_center = 'TC'
    instructor = 'IN'
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (training_center, 'Training center'),
        (instructor, 'Instructor'),
        (user, 'User'),
    )
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES, default=user)
```

forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
     Type = forms.ModelChoiceField(
             widget=forms.RadioSelect(
                 attrs=dict(required=True,
                            render_value=False)
             ),
             queryset=Person.objects.values('user_type')
         )
```

Now I have this model and this form , I want a radio button appears with choices in the model: training center , instructor,user,
How can I make the choices get the values from database, and if there is another way to make it, can you mention it and help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the choices defined in your `Person` model to appear in your `RegistrationForm`, you can do it without `ModelChoiceField`.

Use [`ChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) with `Person` model choices.

In your forms.py:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
     user_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Person.USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

Comment: What do you mean by _answer of choice_?

Comment: I mean that I have now 3 choices, I want if he chooses US then It will redirect him to a page and if TC then another page, something like that. 
How can I know it

Comment: You can get the value of selected `user_type` just by accessing the form field's `cleaned_data` value.